# Oauth config file format youtube to reddit video bot

Tags: python, oauth, youtube, reddit

As the title suggests, I am having problems with a bot designed to automatically mirror/upload videos from a youtube channel I own (to a subreddit I own) using [this bot](https://gitlab.com/EDGYALLCAPSUSERNAME/Youtube-Submitter-Bot/tree/master).

I am having some trouble and am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Youtube-Submitter-Bot-master>python youtubesubmitter_bot.py
Your OAuth2Util config file is in an old format and needs to be changed.
```

I tried as best as I could to migrate it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "youtube_submitter_bot.py", line 201, in main()
  File "youtube_submitter_bot.py", line 148, in main
    o = OAuth2Util.OAuth2Util(r, print_log=True)
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OAuth2Util\OAuth2Util.py", line 156, in __init_
    self._set_app_info()
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OAuth2Util\OAuth2Util.py", line 173, in _set_app_info
    self.r.set_oauth_app_info(self._get_value(CONFIGKEY_APP_KEY), 
AttributeError: 'Reddit' object has no attribute 'set_oauth_app_info'
```

The format of the oauth config file is **.txt**, I couldn't find an updated file format or documentation on one anywhere.

The bot hasen't been updated in 2 years and I know things have changed, any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The bot you linked was written over two years ago and expects PRAW 3. You have installed a version of PRAW post version 3, probably the latest (5.4.0 as of now). PRAW 4 renamed and reworked most methods, so code that was written for PRAW 3 is not compatible with newer versions of PRAW.

To solve this problem, you could install PRAW 3 using `pip install 'praw==3.6.2' --force-reinstall`. Better yet, you could use some other bot that is written for PRAW 4+.